# Pic18F2550 Assembly xt_xt

Tags: microcontroller, pic, assembly

I am trying to set up a Serial Port for a PIC18F2550 Microchip. I am using MPLAB.

In the 18F2550TMPO.ASM Template the statement CONFIG FOSC = XT_XT ;XT oscillator, XT used by USB.

I need to change it, so I am looking for the right statement. I could not find CONFIG FOSC = XT_XT in the MPASM™ Assembler User’s Guide or the PIC18F2455/2550/4455/4550 Datasheet.
 I typed it into google and it did not come up anywhere.

Where would I find this information that follows the same format used in the 18F2550TMPO.ASM Template  provided by Microchip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's described in comments the file "P18F2550.INC", a section of which I've reproduced below:

```
;   Oscillator Selection bits:
;     FOSC = XT_XT         XT oscillator (XT)
;     FOSC = XTPLL_XT      XT oscillator, PLL enabled (XTPLL)
;     FOSC = ECIO_EC       EC oscillator, port function on RA6 (ECIO)
;     FOSC = EC_EC         EC oscillator, CLKO function on RA6 (EC)
;     FOSC = ECPLLIO_EC    EC oscillator, PLL enabled, port function on RA6 (ECPIO)
;     FOSC = ECPLL_EC      EC oscillator, PLL enabled, CLKO function on RA6 (ECPLL)
;     FOSC = INTOSCIO_EC   Internal oscillator, port function on RA6, EC used by USB (INTIO)
;     FOSC = INTOSC_EC     Internal oscillator, CLKO function on RA6, EC used by USB (INTCKO)
;     FOSC = INTOSC_XT     Internal oscillator, XT used by USB (INTXT)
;     FOSC = INTOSC_HS     Internal oscillator, HS oscillator used by USB (INTHS)
;     FOSC = HS            HS oscillator (HS)
;     FOSC = HSPLL_HS      HS oscillator, PLL enabled (HSPLL)
```

The actual values used for CONFIG1H are also in that file:

```
;----- CONFIG1H Options --------------------------------------------------
_FOSC_XT_XT_1H       EQU  H'F0'    ; XT oscillator (XT)
_FOSC_XTPLL_XT_1H    EQU  H'F2'    ; XT oscillator, PLL enabled (XTPLL)
_FOSC_ECIO_EC_1H     EQU  H'F4'    ; EC oscillator, port function on RA6 (ECIO)
_FOSC_EC_EC_1H       EQU  H'F5'    ; EC oscillator, CLKO function on RA6 (EC)
_FOSC_ECPLLIO_EC_1H  EQU  H'F6'    ; EC oscillator, PLL enabled, port function on RA6 (ECPIO)
_FOSC_ECPLL_EC_1H    EQU  H'F7'    ; EC oscillator, PLL enabled, CLKO function on RA6 (ECPLL)
_FOSC_INTOSCIO_EC_1H EQU  H'F8'    ; Internal oscillator, port function on RA6, EC used by USB (INTIO)
_FOSC_INTOSC_EC_1H   EQU  H'F9'    ; Internal oscillator, CLKO function on RA6, EC used by USB (INTCKO)
_FOSC_INTOSC_XT_1H   EQU  H'FA'    ; Internal oscillator, XT used by USB (INTXT)
_FOSC_INTOSC_HS_1H   EQU  H'FB'    ; Internal oscillator, HS oscillator used by USB (INTHS)
_FOSC_HS_1H          EQU  H'FC'    ; HS oscillator (HS)
_FOSC_HSPLL_HS_1H    EQU  H'FE'    ; HS oscillator, PLL enabled (HSPLL)
```

The MPASM Assembler documentation directs you to the .INC file:

[image: ASM]

Comment: I looked for many things in the past few weeks, their are questions like this in all the different forums. With the help of stackexchange I have found many of my questions answered.